# About measurability for operator-valued functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Being $E_1$ and $E_2$ Banach spaces, and working in a finite measure space, I have the following two definitions of measurability for a function $f:\Omega\to\mathcal{L}(E_1,E_2)$:

$\bullet$ I say a function $f$ is type-1 measurable if we can find a sequence of simple functions $s_n:\Omega\to\mathcal{L}(E_1,E_2)$ such that:

$$s_n(\omega)(x)\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} f(\omega)(x), \forall x\in E_1,\;\forall\omega\in \Omega\setminus{A}, \text{where } A \text{ has zero measure.}$$

$\bullet$ And a function $f$ is type-2 measurable if $\forall x\in E_1$, the function $f(\omega)(x)$ is measurable  (the sequence of simple functions can be different for each $x$ in this case).

It's easy to see that type-1 measurability implies type-2 measurability.

What is giving me problems, and this is my question, is how to find an example of a function which is type-2 measurable, but not type-1 measurable.

Thanks a lot for any idea.

Comment: I can think of a simpler situation which is somewhat like this; it may give you some intuition for constructing your example. Consider $\Omega = [0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure as a probability space. For $t \in [0,1]$, define a stochastic process by $X_t(\omega) = 1$ if $\omega = t$ and $0$ otherwise. Then for each $t$, $\mathbb{P}( \{ \omega : X_t(\omega)=0 \})=1$ but $\mathbb{P}( \{ \omega : \forall t \in [0,1] \, X_t(\omega) = 0 \}) = 0$. As a consequence, this process has the same finite dimensional distributions as the constant zero process, but it is a.s. discontinuous.

Comment: Being a little clearer, you should make an example where the pointwise convergence of the sequence of simple functions fails on a null set $N(x)$ for each $x$. Then build a set of positive measure as an uncountable union of these null sets. In my example this was to write $[0,1] = \bigcup_{x \in [0,1]} \{ x \}$.

Comment: Still fighting against this. I think involving non-separable spaces can be useful, but still can't get the desired example. When I find a function which is not type-1 measurable, it always results not being type-2 measurable also...